# Device screen turns black after opening camera intent

Tags: android, android-camera-intent

[SOLVED] I don't know why it was doing that but all I had to do was to restart my phone and it started to work again. Happy coding everyone! :)

I have been developing an app where you can capture images and post them. The camera intent has been working great previously but today when I built the app to my mobile phone and tried to open the camera intent after few changes in a whole different activity, (which should not affect the camera at all) the whole app freezes and after few seconds of doing nothing, it brought up a black screen where I can't even see my phones "home", "back" and "close apps" buttons at the bottom of the screen. The app doesn't crash nor give me any error messages but the black screen doesn't go away before I press the spot where my phones home button should be and close the app after.

I have asked the permission to use the camera and that works fine but after that comes the black screen. And as a said the camera has been working during many weeks of developing but just today it started doing this.

Here is my code for the camera intent:

```
    //ADD NEW SPOT
public void addNewSpot(View v)
{
    //CHECKING PERMISSION FOR CAMERA
    if (checkCallingOrSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE);
    }
    else
    {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
        {
            File photoFile = null;
            try
            {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (photoFile != null)
            {
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    }
}


//CHECK FOR THE RESULT FROM CAMERA ACTIVITY
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults)
{
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

    if (requestCode == MY_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CODE)
    {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
                File photoFile = null;
                try
                {
                    photoFile = createImageFile();
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (photoFile != null)
                {
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
                    StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder();
                    StrictMode.setVmPolicy(builder.build());
                    startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


//CREATE FOLDER FOR THE IMAGE
String imageFilePath;

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "IMG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );

    imageFilePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}


//GET TAKEN IMAGE, DOWNSCALE IT AND SEND IT TO CROPPING
File compressedImageFile;

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
        File f = new File(imageFilePath);
        try
        {
            compressedImageFile = new Compressor(this).compressToFile(f);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            String message = e.getMessage();
            Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(compressedImageFile);
        mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
        this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);

        CropImage.activity(contentUri)
                .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                .start(this);
    }

    //CROP THE IMAGE
    if(requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
        CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

            Intent addPostIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, add_new_spot.class);
            addPostIntent.putExtra("imagePath", resultUri.toString());
            startActivity(addPostIntent);
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Image can't be cropped, please try again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the intent to work fine since it has been working before but instead it makes the app freeze in a black screen and force the user to restart the app. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what happens if the user denies camera permission and clicks on "never ask again" checkbox? I don't see you cater to that scenario. Maybe that's the reason why your camera intent isn't launching and it leaves you with a black screen. To elaborate, after the user makes the choice above, the requestPermissions method will be blocked.

Comment: There isn't actually option to check "never ask again". I think it is ether yes or no and thats it. I uninstalled the app and made sure I pressed yes/allow but it happened again. It is very weird because if I go away from the app and come back to the black screen I left it on, the second I press the app from my running apps tab the whole phone freezes for a moment before going to the my app.

Comment: if the user is shown the permissions dialog after they've already denied it once in the past, it has the checkbox I mentioned earlier